# How to cast to my UIViewController

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

I'm tearing my hair out on this one. I have a menu view that has 2 buttons. Each button has been routed to another view controller via separate segue identifiers. That is, they both point to the same view controller, but under different segues.

My research all over indicates that I need to 'cast' to my destination view controller, and I cannot for the life of me find code that works, nor, perhaps more perplexing, WHERE to put that code.

These are the properties in my DESTINATION / TankCalculatorViewController view controller header file:

```
// Properties for segue identifiers
@property(nonatomic, readonly) NSString *tankCalcOne;
@property(nonatomic, readonly) NSString *tankCalcTwo;
```

This code is in my MENU implementation file:

```
// This allows the view for tankCalcOne or Two depending on which button is clicked in the menu

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    //cast???

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"tankCalcOne"])
    {
        [[segue destinationViewController] TankCalculatorViewController:self];
    }
    else ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"tankCalcTwo"]);
    {
    [[segue destinationViewController] TankCalculatorViewController:self];
    }
 }
```

I have seen dozens of answers here saying things like, "You need to cast to your custom class," but none of the code examples I have seen exactly apply to what I am doing, and I have no idea where to put said code. I am guessing it would go in the header for the destination view controller, and then I would import TankCalculatorViewController.h into my menu implementation, but that's really a shot in the dark. I have been taking a crash course in this world, and even after a few months working with this language, some of the concepts and certainly the nomenclature is still sinking in. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

If it helps, I am getting the following error in my if/then:

'No known instance instance method for selector TankCalculatorViewController'

Thanks in advance.

Comment: **[((MyViewController*)[segue destinationViewController]) TankCalculatorViewController:self];** try this to cast it

Answer (score 1):

it simple do as c concept like

```
[(MyControllerClassName *)[segue destinationViewController]TankCalculatorViewController:self]];
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Like I asked above, where would I put this code? In the destination header? Somewhere in the code I have already put in the menu implementation?

Comment: you used prepareForSegue method

Comment: I did, indeed. So does this code go inside that method? Am I replacing 'MyControllerClass' in your code with 'TankCalculatorViewController'?

Comment: `[(TankCalculatorViewController *)[segue destinationViewController]TankCalculatorViewController:self]];' just before the "if" statement is throwing the following errors: Parse issue / expected ], undeclared identifier TankCalculatorViewController, as well as No Known Instance Method for TankCalculatorViewController.

Answer (score 0):

I have been doing like this

```
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"InvoiceDetail"])
{
    IVInvoiceDetailViewController *detailViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
    detailViewController.yourString = self.yourStringObject;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am not seeing how this applies to what I am trying to do. My destination view is basically a calculator, but I need 2 of them running at the same time independently. I am not using a table view.

Comment: you can use your string here, let me update code, like this you can pass your current controller data to another controller and manage that

Comment: I am not trying to pass data between controllers. The above method is bringing up more variable than I think I need. Not sure where yourString, yourStringObject are to be found. I just want to be able to open separate versions of my calculator view. They don't need to share any data.

Comment: When you push your controller its fresh as new and you can do anything which you want, can you clear why do you need a separate one and current one

Comment: It's part of the functionality of my particular app. The two calculators need to run at the same time, independently of one another.

Comment: then you need to store the state of every calculator so that when you come and go back you can initialise the controller with its last state, because when you go back controller get dealloc and there is no data that you could use or store when you push your controller again

Comment: Oh man. I was afraid of that. I don't even know where to start on that. Any tips where I should start? I am going to do some searching right now.

Comment: you can use encoding for your current data of calculator and the load back or you can use coredata for read and write back